# Multi-layered comparison histogram

Tags: d3.js

I need to build a histogram using the d3.js library. The histogram should look like the one below. The main objective of this histogram is to compare two sets of results. The results that are shown in the diagram below represent data gathered over the same days of the month, but in two different months (say 1st - 6th of January (green) and February (blue)).

The histogram that I currently have basically shows the correct data, just that it does not overlay them (or even show them side-by-side). Instead it shows them ordered by the date, the results representing January first (to the left), and the ones representing February second (to the right). What should I do in order to have them show side-by-side?

Edit: I work in an Angular environment, and I use a prebuilt directive for showing the graph. The code for the directive is lcoated at https://github.com/fullscale/dangle/blob/master/dist/dangle.datehisto.js

Desired result:

[image: desired chart]

Current result:

[image: current chart]

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: I have updated the question. I work in an Angular environment, and I use a prebuilt directive for showing the graph. The code for the directive is located at https://github.com/fullscale/dangle/blob/master/dist/dangle.datehisto.js

I specifically would at least like to know if this is possible, using d3.

Comment: It's certainly possible. Is what you've posted the actual output of the script? It doesn't look like it would produce that to me. In particular, I don't see anything that would add two sets of bars to the same SVG.

Comment: What I currently do is I join the two arrays of data that I have (for January and February), and bind them to the SVG. The colors in my sketchy diagram are just for better graphical representation on SO. If you say that what I want is possible, can you point me in a direction on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: So you're currently getting the two bars on top of each other? You could simply add or subtract a small value to shift them, e.g. something like `.attr('x', function(d,i) { return x(d.time) + (i%2 ? 10 : -10); })`.

Comment: No, I currently have `Jan1 Jan2 Jan3 Jan4 Jan5 Jan6 Feb1 Feb2 Feb3 Feb4 Feb5 Feb6`. What I want is `Jan1 Feb1 Jan2 Feb2 Jan3 Feb3 Jan4 Feb4 Jan5 Feb5 Jan6 Feb6`.

Comment: Probably easiest to just change the February dates to January and use the code above then.

Comment: The only reason I am not very happy with this solution is that the labels below the bars would all become January, making it hard to differentiate the two months.

Comment: No, as it's only one month they would all just show the day.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are using a time scale when it should really be linear for what you are trying to do.  You don't want your x offset to increase based on the actual date/time, but instead just on the date.getDate() portion of the date.  Assuming d.time represents the same thing as `new Date().getTime()`, then you can change your scale to linear and use just the day plus an offset for the month to determine your x values.  This will require you to build some form of legend to indicate the months though.

First change the scale we are using:

```
// create x,y scales (x is inferred as time)
// var x = d3.time.scale()
//    .range([0, width]);
//
// Use linear scale since we really care about the day portion of the date/time
var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, width]);
```

Then calculate our month and day ranges:

```
// Get the range of months so we can use the month
// to offset the x value for overlay
var monthExtent = d3.extent(data,function(d) { 
            var date = new Date(); 
            date.setTime(d.time.getTime()); 
            return date.getMonth(); 
        });

// Get the range of days for the graph
// If you always want to display the whole month
// var dateExtent = [0,31]
//
// Otherwise calculate the range
var dateExtent = d3.extent(data,function(d) {  
            var date = new Date(); 
            date.setTime(d.time.getTime()); 
            return date.getDate(); 
        });
```

Then set the x domain to our day range:

```
// recalculate the x and y domains based on the new data.
 // we have to add our "interval" to the max otherwise 
 // we don't have enough room to draw the last bar.
 //
 //x.domain([
 //    d3.min(data, function(d) { 
 //        return d.time;
 //    }), 
 //    d3.max(data, function(d) { 
 //        return d.time;
 //    })
 //]);


 // Our x domain is just the range of days 
 x.domain(dateExtent);
```

Add a color scale to differentiate between months:

```
// Set up a color scale to separate months
 var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

Now, change the x attribute to use the day value plus an offset for the month to create the overlay. I used 20 pixels here but you could easily change it to a percentage of teh bar width instead.  Then add a fill attribute using the month and color scale so that each month gets it's own color.

```
bars.enter()
    .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'histo rect ')
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            // Extract the day portion of the date/time
            // and then offset the rect by it's month value
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(d.time.getTime());
            return x(date.getDate()) + (date.getMonth() - monthExtent[0]) * 20; 
        })
        .attr("fill",function(d) { 
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(d.time);
            return color(date.getMonth()); 
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height })
        .attr('width', barWidth)
        .transition()
            .delay(function (d,i){ return i * 0; })
            .duration(500)
                .attr('height', function(d) { return height - y(d.count); })
                .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.count); });
```

Finally, you'll probably have to change how the barWidth is calculated to make sure there is the right amount of space between each day. Hopefully this helps!